# Test a program that uses tty stdin and stdout

Tags: c++, python, stdout, stdin, tty

I have a software made of two halves: one is python running on a first pc, the other is cpp running on a second one.
They communicate through the serial port (tty).

I would like to test the python side on my pc, feeding it with the proper data and see if it behaves as expected.

I started using subprocess but then came the problem: which stdin and stdout should I supply?

`cStringIO` does not work because there is no `fileno()`

PIPE doesn't work either because `select.select()` says there is something to read even if nothing it's actually sent

Do you have any hints? Is there a fake tty module I can use?

Comment: Maybe you can `mock` them and define `return_value` too.

Comment: *"`select.select()` says there is something to read even if nothing it's actually sent"* -- what does `os.read` return in this case? Have you tried `pexpect`, `pty` modules?

Comment: Regarding the not working PIPE: did you check thoroughly? Low level pipes work well with select on Linux (side note: this combination is used in a so called self-pipe trick to reliably handle signals). And select returns also for EOF.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should mock that out and just test the behavior, without relying too much on terminal IO.  You can use [mock.patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object) for that. Say you want to test `t_read`:

```
@mock.patch.object(stdin, 'fileno')
@mock.patch.object(stdin, 'read')
def test_your_behavior(self, mock_read, mock_fileno):
    # this should make select.select return what you expect it to return
    mock_fileno.return_value = 'your expected value' 

    # rest of the test goes here...
```

If you can post at least part of the code you're trying to test, I can maybe give you a better example.

Comment: Code is https://github.com/arduino/YunBridge, packet.py in particular https://github.com/arduino/YunBridge/blob/master/bridge/packet.py

[1]